# Why endianness mismatch happens in this code?

Tags: javascript, endianness, binary-data

Here is simple piece of code from this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vo0aL8h4/2/
It is about a binary endianness issue while making a cross-browser binary data reader/writer code.

> I was wrong here as well
>
> That `0x00000101` is 257 in decimal, it was saved to a binary file as
> Uint32. Is it little endian representation, yes?

It is very strange that it is being read incorrectly by DataView.getUint32 .
So I created a fiddle to check in browser an issue I experienced in Node.

```js
let data = new Uint8Array([0,0,1,1]);
let view = new DataView(data.buffer);
writeLog(`reading little endian data (${data.join()}):  ${view.getUint32(0, true)}`);
writeLog(`reading big endian data (${data.join()}):  ${view.getUint32(0, false)}`);
```

Output:

```
reading little endian data (0,0,1,1): 16842752
reading big endian data (0,0,1,1): 257
```

What I missing? Is that DataView.getUint32 vs setUint32 work differently about

## Update

Thanks for your comments and answer. it inspired me to re-check whether the endianness flag applied properly.

This code was a bug:

```js
    constructor(littleEndian?:boolean) {
        if (littleEndian === undefined) {
            this.#littleEndian = isMachineLittleEndian;
        }
    }
```

and it was incorrect implementation, it was missing branch.

Correct version:

```js
    constructor(littleEndian?:boolean) {
        if (littleEndian === undefined) {
            this.#littleEndian = isMachineLittleEndian;
        } else {
            this.#littleEndian = !!littleEndian;
        }
    }
```

Hope this question and answers will help someone as an example of what happens if you provide somewhere `undefined` to setUint32 and later set a `true` value in `getUint32`.

Comment: `Is it little endian representation, yes?` is that a question or a statement? `UInt32` doesn't *declare* an endianness, it declares an unsigned 32 bit integer and that is all

Comment: `0x000000101` when little-endian is `16842752` ... i.e. it's `00 + 00*256 + 01*256*256 + 01*256*256*256` ... perhaps you misunderstand what endian-ness refers to?

Comment: "*it was saved to a binary file as Uint32*" - **how** did you save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That 0x00000101 is 257 in decimal, it was saved to a binary file as
> Uint32. Is it little endian representation, yes?

No, that's big-endian, because the most-significant byte is first.

You need to do this:

```js
let data = new Uint8Array([0,0,1,1]);
let view = new DataView(data.buffer);
console.log(view.getUint32(0, false)); // prints 257
```

Comment: 0x101₁₆/257₁₀ does not have any endianness at all, it's just a number.

Comment: @Bergi the question states that the number represented by the byte sequence (hex 000000101) is supposed to be the number 257. This implies that the byte sequence is a big-endian representation of the number 257.